# Mysql getting latest information from parameters table

Tags: mysql

I have a database that has this columns:
id, object_id, name, value, timestamp

There are a lot of object parameters inside this database. For every object_id I have records:

```
id    object_id    name   value       timestamp
1     20           event  data         2016-08-10 17:00:00
2     20           event  hist         2016-08-10 18:00:00
3     20           event  data         2016-08-10 19:00:00
4     20           event  hist         2016-08-10 16:00:00
5     20           source  device      2016-08-10 17:00:00
6     20           source  device      2016-08-10 18:00:00
7     20           source  webservice  2016-08-10 19:00:00
8     20           source  webservice  2016-08-10 16:00:00
```

So I would have the data that was actual at for example 2016-08-10 19:00:08:

```
3     20           event  data         2016-08-10 19:00:00
7     20           source  webservice  2016-08-10 19:00:00
```

I used untill now this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM table st1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) as id 
            FROM table 
            WHERE object_id = 20 AND timestamp <= '2016-08-10 19:00:08' 
            GROUP BY `name`) st2 
ON st2.id = st1.id  
WHERE object_id = 20
```

This worked great, because the max(id) had always the latest info, but now that isn't anymore...

What query should I use to solve this issue?

Comment: MCVE - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You could order by timestamp:

```
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
```

And add a condition where timestamp must newer than say, an hour ago. UNIX_TIMESTAMP() will turn it into an integer you can manipulate in that way.

Comment: This doesn't seems to give me the expected result.

    SELECT * 
    FROM table st1 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) as id 
                FROM table 
                WHERE object_id = 20 AND timestamp <= '2016-08-10 19:00:08' 
                GROUP BY `name` order by timestamp desc) st2 
    ON st2.id = st1.id  
    WHERE object_id = 20

The one hour difference is here just an example..